# C# string does not contain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, contains

I am trying to delete items from a list 'scholarships' that do not contain string 'States' in its 'Student_state'attribute.

```
if (States != "")
            {
                scholarships.RemoveAll(s => !s.Student_state.Contains(States));
                scholarships.RemoveAll(s => s.Student_state == null);
            }
```

The ! character did not accomplish this. Any ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate with s.Student_state is.

Comment: Student_state is an attribute of entity Scholarship. The 's' is a part of the lambda statement 's => s'

Comment: Is the 'student_state' a status or a location? Removing items based on if a string contains a value -could- have ill side-effects. For instance if using it for location states such as 'Virginia', scholarships for students in 'West Virginia' will be removed as well.

Comment: Great point. It is a location.

Comment: student_state is a custom Location object, a List/Dictionary of strings or something else?

Comment: @SRiley22 explain what you mean "*did not accomplish this*". What kind of data it missed to remove?

Comment: Please provide an example. In particular, what can the `States` variable contain? Just one state name? Or multiple state names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible a case sensitivity issue?  String.Contains does a case sensitive test.  I have used the following to achieve a case insensitive test in the past:

```
(s.Student_state.IndexOf(States, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == -1)
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for the variable States, not the string "States" (unless of course that variable is "States").

Your code should be:

```
if (States != "")
{
  scholarships.RemoveAll(s => !s.Student_state.Contains("States"));
  scholarships.RemoveAll(s => s.Student_state == null);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, should have been more clear, it is a variable "States."

Comment: @SRiley22, Ok, could you post some sample data? If that is the case it looks like your code should work. If you look at the return value of the function is it 0? More generally, how do you know it isn't working as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? The sequence of statements is important here.

```
if (States != "")
{
    scholarships.RemoveAll(s => s.Student_state == null);
    scholarships.RemoveAll(s => !s.Student_state.Contains("States"));      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about only select the ones you want?

```
if (States != "")
{
    scholarships = scholarships.Where(s=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Student_state) && s.Student_state.Contains(States)).ToList();
}
```